# Extracting all text after a phrase and then adding file names at the start of each line?

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I'm working on a bibliometrics project with ~3k text documents and I'm trying to figure out how to get from unstructured text to a list of citations. The formatting varies a lot, but they all end with a Works Cited. So far, I've come up with this:

```
sed -n '/Works Cited/,$p' Jones.txt > newfile.txt
```

After running that on all ~3k documents, I'll combine them all for analysis. But it would be meaningful to know which lines/citations came from which document. So my best guess is that would involve 2 steps:

1. Extract the lines following the phrase Works Cited.
2. Insert the file name at the start of each line. (There's no standard metadata structure or even a consistent line where authors, titles, etc appear.)

For example, for a document named Jones.txt:

> ...Vivamus fringilla dapibus volutpat. Phasellus nec mattis orci, vitae ornare >tellus. Nunc at porta libero. Cras non ipsum id justo auctor ullamcorper. Lorem >ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec nulla tincidunt, >venenatis nisi a, pharetra neque. Morbi euismod id mauris vitae imperdiet. Nam >sagittis mattis urna vel consectetur. Integer rhoncus leo at sagittis >sollicitudin.
>
> Works Cited
>
> Jones, Ted. Biology. New York: Penguin, 2009.
>
> Smith, Mary. "Butterflies and Biology." Journal 21.2 (2013): 1-10.

I'd like to produce this:

> Jones.txt, Jones, Ted. Biology. New York: Penguin, 2009.
>
> Jones.txt, Smith, Mary. "Butterflies and Biology." Journal 21.2 (2013): 1-10.

Is this possible? Is there a better way to think about it? I tried scouring SO and other places for solutions, but maybe I'm not looking for the right phrases. Would this be best in sed, perl, etc? Will the solution change to run *.txt rather than just Jones.txt?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

-JCC

Comment: is there anything that shows the end of a work being cited? or anything that shows the beginning of the next text?  If not, you'll need to give more examples of the Works Cited so patterns can be derived

Comment: Each cited work is on a separate line that ends with a period, but each text is also in a separate file so I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: using the `ms` flags it will get you all the Works Cited in a group then run another regex to split those up.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using GNU `awk`

You don't mention your operating system but, assuming that you have access to GNU `awk`, try:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{f=0} f && /./{printf "%s, ", FILENAME} f{print} /Works Cited/{f=1}' *.txt

Jones.txt, Jones, Ted. Biology. New York: Penguin, 2009.

Jones.txt, Smith, Mary. "Butterflies and Biology." Journal 21.2 (2013): 1-10.
```

Note that, in this solution, you can specify all your file names on the command line at once, via `*.txt` in the abovee example, and GNU `awk` updates the variable `FILENAME` as it switches from one file to the next.

How it works:

- `FNR==1{f=0}`

  On the first line of every file, set flag `f` to zero to signify that we haven't yet seen the `Works Cited` line for this file.
- `f && /./{printf "%s, ", FILENAME}`

  If flag `f` is non-zero (meaning `Works Cited` has already been seen) and if the line is non-blank (there is at least one character on the line), then print the filename followed by a comma and a space.
- `f{print}`

  If the flag `f` is nonzero, print the whole line.
- `/Works Cited/{f=1}`

  If this line contains `Works Cited`, then set flag `f` to one.

The `FILENAME` variable is a GNU extension.

#### Non-GNU `awk`

For versions of `awk` which do not support `FILENAME`, we can use a shell loop, setting the `awk` variable `name` to the name of each file in turn:

```
for f in *.txt
do 
    awk -v name="$f" 'f && /./{printf name ", "} f{print} /Works Cited/{f=1}' "$f"
done
```

#### Using `sed`

If you really must use `sed`, try:

```
for f in *.txt
do
    sed -n '/Works Cited/,${/Works Cited/d; /./ s/^/'"$f, /;p}" "$f"
done
```

This approach is acceptable if you are *sure* that your file names do not contain any sed-active characters.

Comment: Very good replies. Note: assuming (for sed) there is no special char in file name (`\&`) that is normaly the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this in one step with a simple perl script.

Basic Usage:

```
extract.pl myoutfile.txt
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict 'vars';
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

my $outfile   = $ARGV[0] || 'citations.out';
my $split_on  = $ARGV[1] || 'Works Cited';
my $filetypes = $ARGV[2] || 'txt';

# Open Outfile
open(my $fh_outfile, '>', $outfile) 
  or die "Could not open file '$outfile' $!";

# Get list of files
my @files = <*.$filetypes>;
my $count = scalar @files;
my $current = 0;

# Scan files
foreach my $file (@files) {
  say "\nWorking on: $file [ " . ++$current  .  " / $count ]";

  # Read in the file contents
  my @contents = do {
    open my $fh, "<", $file
        or die "Could not open $file $!";
    <$fh>;
  };

  my $split_found = 0;
  foreach my $line ( @contents ) {
    # Write to output file, only when in
    # works cited section, and line isn't empty
    if ( $split_found && $line =~ m/\w/ ) {
      print $fh_outfile "$file, $line";
      print "   >$file, $line";
    }

    # Flag 'Works Cited' section
    $split_found = $split_found || $line =~ m/^$split_on\s*$/g;
  }
};

close $fh_outfile;
```